# Excel - Check if numerical day is between two dates

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, excel-2007

Good afternoon SO community,

Here is a little setup to help everybody understand the situation.

```
Sheet1!B3 has the date 'Tuesday, July 26, 2016'
Sheet1!B4 has the date "Tuesday, August 02, 2016'

Sheet2!C5 has the value of 1.
```

The value in Sheet2!C5 represents the day of the month. For example, this case would be the first of the month. I'm trying to figure out how to check to see if the value in Sheet2!C5 is between the dates in Sheet1!B3 and Sheet1!B4.

**Here's what I've tried:**

```
=IF(AND(Sheet2!C5>DAY(B3),Sheet2!C5<(DAY(B3)+7)),"True","False")

=IF(AND(Sheet2!C5>B3,Sheet2!C5<(B3)+7),"True","False")

=IF(AND(Sheet2!C5>DAY(B3),Sheet2!C5<DAY(B4)),"True","False")

=IF(AND(Sheet2!C5>B3,Sheet2!C5<B4),"True","False")
```

None of those formulas work due to the fact that the day of the month would end at 31 or 30 and restart at 1.

Does anybody have any ideas on what I could try to get this to work?

Thank you in advance,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula entered as an array formula by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

```
=OR(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(Sheet1!B3 &":"&Sheet1!B4)))=Sheet2!C5)
```

The `ROW(INDIRECT...` returns an array of all the dates from B3:B4 inclusive.  We then use the `DAY` function to return the days of the month, and compare that to C5.

Note that this method will fail for any dates after 24-NOV-4770 using current versions of excel..  Hopefully that will not be an issue.

Comment: Ah, that works quite well... Only issues is that I need to be able to have custom results. (Something other than true/false). Any ideas on how to do that part with the above formula?

Comment: **HINT:** From your post, I would think you are familiar with the `IF` function.  The `logical_test` argument in an `IF` function is a formula that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  ...

Comment: I understand that the logical_test would return true of false. Using a generic IF statement, would allow you to say something if the statement returns true, and something else if it returns false. I simply surrounded what you posted with an IF statement. (=IF(OR(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(Sheet1!B5 &":"&Sheet1!B6)))=Sheet2!C5)=TRUE,"Yes","No"))

Comment: @Timothy_Bomer  Since the function already returns the Boolean, there is no need to retest it.  Simpler:  `=IF(OR(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(Sheet1!B3 &":"&Sheet1!B4)))=Sheet2!C5),"Yes","No")`

Comment: You're right. That makes sense. One last question. If I change the formula to `=IF(OR(DAY(ROW(INDIRECT(Sheet1!B3 &":"&Sheet1!B4 - 1)))=Sheet2!C5),Sheet2!D5,"")` , Would it test the dates between B3 and the day before B4?

Comment: @Timothy_Bomer It should.  What happened when you tested it?  You can also use the Formula Evaluation tool to examine exactly how the formula works.